# 'display: none' on SVG element with pattern definitions makes patterns invisible

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a set of SVG definitions which I place at the top of my body.  This svg tag has height and width of 0, but without display:none, it creates space at the top of the document.  To fix this I add display:none.  However, this causes the patterns defined in it to not work when referenced later on in the document.

```
<body>
<svg width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<defs>
<g id="diamond">
  <path d="M50,7 L96,100 L50,193 L4,100 L50,7 Z"></path>
</g>
<g id="oval">
  <path d="M3,150 L3,50 C3,24.084 24,3 50,3 C76,3 97,24 97,50 L97,150 C97,176 75.916,197 50,197 C24.084,197 3,176 3,150 Z"></path>
</g>
<g id="squiggle">
  <path d="M25,77 C25,48 4,45 4,25 C4,14 18,3 40,3 C66,3 92,21 92,54 C92,86 75,100 75,123 C75,152 96,155 96,175 C96,186 82,197 60,197 C34,197 8,179 8,146 C8,114 25,100.02465 25,77 Z"></path>
</g>
<pattern id="triangle" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <polygon points="5,0 10,10 0,10"></polygon>
</pattern>
<pattern id="green-stripes" x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" style="display:inline-block;">
  <rect x="0" y="7" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: 1px; fill: green;"></rect>
</pattern>
<pattern id="red-stripes" x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" style="display:inline-block;">
  <rect x="0" y="7" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: 1px; fill: red;"></rect>
</pattern>
<pattern id="purple-stripes" x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" style="display:inline-block;">
  <rect x="0" y="7" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: 1px; fill: purple;"></rect>
</pattern>
</defs>
</svg>
<div class="topbar"></div>
<div id="game">
    <div class="cardrow">
    <div class="card purple-card" id="oqFqnSBH6zMRc5hJr" width="100" height="200">
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond" style="stroke: purple; fill: none;"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond" style="stroke: purple; fill: none;"></use>
  </svg>
  </div>
 <div class="card red-card" id="xPibDdNYe2vAgDYKK" width="100" height="200">
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond" style="stroke: red; fill: none;"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond" style="stroke: red; fill: none;"></use>
  </svg>
  </div>    
    <div class="card purple-card" id="MgATXd9RTv52MKFtp" width="100" height="200">
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond" style="stroke: purple; fill: url(#purple-stripes);"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#diamond" style="stroke: purple; fill: url(#purple-stripes);"></use>
  </svg>
  </div>
    <div class="card red-card" id="mzpSYNnFXFX9SjPLa" width="100" height="200">
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#oval" style="stroke: red; fill: none;"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#oval" style="stroke: red; fill: none;"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg width="100" height="200" z-index="-40" style="display:inline-block">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#oval" style="stroke: red; fill: none;"></use>
  </svg>
  </div>
  </div>
</div></body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vahkogdk/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could replace display:none by position:absolute  and no more space taken by the definition svg:

```
    <svg width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vahkogdk/1/

Comment: Great answer. It also works with `display: block` instead of `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved by putting the `svg` tag inside the `head` tag

Comment: Not always there's "direct" access to `head`. Say the `svg` element is in nth child template, and it's not worth the time to go though the stack to get to parent. Also, when put in `head` all pages will render it, but not all should do so.

Comment: @mlen108 why would pages render it when it's in the `head`? That should not happen. They document request would _load_ it however, granted.

Comment: yeah I meant "load" and not "render", you're right. if the svg is large this could be an issue, and some folks won't be bothered nonetheless.